# What happens when a seed contains a locked item?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

Say I found a seed which contains an item I just unlocked, right in the first item room. What happens when a new player, who hasn't unlocked that item, plays my seed? I would guess one of the following situations would happen:

1. The 'locked' item will be substituted by an item that isn't locked for the new player;
2. All the items in the seed will be different, because the new player has a different item pool;
3. The entire run will be different, including the rooms and such (RNG will derail);
4. Nothing is different, the new player can obtain the item that is actually still locked.

Has someone tested which of these cases happens?

Comment: I barely have anything unlocked if anyone has a good seed to test this with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The item you have not unlocked will be replaced by a random item that you have unlocked. (Your option 1.)

Comment: I would have thought it would still exist.  Seeded runs don't count towards either achievements or unlocking items.